FLUTTER: APK from adb pull from an app(my app) downloaded from play store is debug signed when I use apksigner to verify it
I currently published an App on Play store, when I download the app on play store and pull the apk from my phone using 'adb pull' then use apksigner to verify it, the result shows that it is on debug mode "Signer #1 certificate DN: CN=Android, OU=Android, O=Google Inc., L=Mountain View, ST=California, C=US".
I tried generating an apk and appbundle, check it using apksigner/keytool and it is properly release signed.
but again when I generate appbundle and publish it on playstore or internal testing and do the same steps above, the apk becomes debug signed again.
Am I missing something out?
I tried downloading my flutter app from playstore and extract its apk from my phone using adb pull, scanned the apk using apksinger. but the result show it is debug signed.
I expect that the result should show the right details from my keystore.jks file

I see, thank you! this explain everything and I also saw and read the AppSigning documentation  and everything you said is true.

Apps you upload for publishing on Play Store are only signed with an upload key. For new apps Google generates and maintains the release key. This key used for signing the APK files generated from the app bundle. Therefore it doesn't matter which key you use for signing the app bundle as long as it is registered as upload key at Google.
